# How to extract values of a pseudo element in an HTMl file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML page,

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    body{
      padding: 30px;
    }
    input[type=range]{
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      border: none;
      width: 12%;
      outline: none;
      background: none;
    }
    input[type=range]:focus{
      outline: none;
    }
    input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track{ 
      height: 4px;
      background: #0d65a6;
    }
    input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb{
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
      border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: #fff;margin-top: -8px;
    }
    input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-thumb{
      border: 1px solid #107aca;
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px #107aca;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <div id="slider-target">
      <span data-reactroot="">
        <input type="range" id="numInput" min="0" max="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="50">
        <br>
        <label id="slider-label">Hidden slider label</label>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I want to extract the value of the pseudo element `:-webkit-slider-runnable-track` and its property `height`.

I tried this query:

```
window.getComputedStyle(
  document.querySelector('#numInput'), 
  ':-webkit-slider-runnable-track'
).getPropertyValue('height')
```

And also

```
window.getComputedStyle(
  document.querySelector("input[type=range]"), 
  ':-webkit-slider-runnable-track'
).getPropertyValue('height')
```

But I am not successfully able to retrieve the value.Since the style tag has no id its difficult to locate it

Comment: Pseudo-elements aren't in the DOM and so can't be selected with JS.

Comment: I tried your code in local and [on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6L3x0m13/) and it works.

Comment: @Paulie_D : Is there any other way to get the pseudo-element values?

Comment: Hi @Robiseb : It works only for one pseudo element.
If I try something like this : alert(window.getComputedStyle(
  document.querySelector('#numInput'),
  ':-webkit-slider-thumb'
).getPropertyValue('height'));

This gives me : 4px. Which is wrong. The correct value should be 20px

Comment: [I made a cheat code](https://jsfiddle.net/6L3x0m13/3/)... it's ugly and **it's not THE answer** but it works. Shameful ! In fact, you can't access those pseudo element (console log `getComputedStyle1`). Even get the height seems lucky